# What does Z subscript + mean in sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

just for general knowledge what does Z subscript + mean in terms of set, i know Z is the set of integers but what does the subscript of "+" mean?

Comment: Positive integers.

Comment: I have seen it some times refering to nonnegative integers, proof wiki identifies it as such http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Symbols:Z unlees it is a typo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $+$ in $\mathbb{Z}_+$ or sometimes written $\mathbb{Z}^+$ means the set of *positive* integers, rather than the typical set of all integers, $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Thank you! i know superscript + meant that but i wasn't sure subscript meant the same

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Bbb{Z}_+ = \Bbb{Z}_{>0} = \{ n \in \Bbb{Z} \mid n > 0 \}
$$

Answer (score 0):

For reals, $\mathbb{R}_+$ means the set of all positive real numbers, i.e. $(0, \infty)$. It seem s funny to me to do the same for integers since all positive itnegers are in $\mathbb{N}$, but I think that's what is meant.

Comment: Some people have $0\in\Bbb N$, which means there is often ambiguity.