# What does $t \in \mathbb{N}_0$ mean?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, bayesian

Some context if it helps: I'm learning [Bayesian filtering](http://www.deepideas.net/robot-localization-recursive-bayesian-estimation/) and there's a bunch of notation I don't get so I'll probably ask a bunch more questions including this one.

Small excerpt from the page:

> changes in the environment take place at discrete, equidistant time steps $t \in \mathbb{N}_0$, where sensor measurements arrive at every time step $t \geq 1$.

I have looked at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641391/what-does-z-subscript-mean-in-sets) and [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382389/what-does-z-subscript-something-mean) and I've concluded that it most likely means all natural numbers from 0 upwards, since anything mod 0 is basically infinity.

Comment: This means that $t$ is an element of $\mathbb{N}_0$, which is (usually) the set of natural numbers along with zero.  That is, $t$ is a nonnegative integer.  That being said, $\mathbb{N}_0$ has nothing to do with the notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$, which is either the group of integers modulo $n$, or the $n$-adic integers (assuming that $n$ is prime).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version:  it is almost certain that
$$ \mathbb{N}_0 = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dotsb \}. $$

In more detail: the question about [the integers modulo $n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/382389/) has nothing to do with the notation $\mathbb{N}_0$.  The notation $\mathbb{Z}_n$ generally refers to the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, which is the group of integers modulo $n$.  That being said, it is worth noting that if we assume that $\mathbb{Z}_0$ refers to the quotient group modulo zero, then $$\mathbb{Z}_0 = \mathbb{Z}/0\mathbb{Z} \cong \mathbb{Z},$$
since $a-b = 0 \pmod{0}$ if and only if $a = b$.  Thus "division by zero" (in this sense) is actually okay.

The notation $\mathbb{Z}_p$ can also refer to the $p$-adic integers, where $p$ is your favorite prime number, but that, also, is neither here nor there.

[The other question that you cite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641391/) is a bit more to the point, though still not quite right.  Yes, $\mathbb{Z}_+$ typically refers to the positive integers, and $\mathbb{R}_+$ is the positive real numbers.  However, this is a notation that specifically deals with ordered groups, rings, or fields.  In such a setting, we want to have a notation for the positive and negative elements, so there it is.  In the case of $\mathbb{N}$, everything is positive and $\mathbb{N}$ isn't even a group, anyway (though it is a monoid!).

In the context of your question, it is nigh certain that $\mathbb{N}_{0}$ refers to the set of *nonnegative integers*.  This is the set of all natural numbers, along with zero (or, if you believe that $0$ is a natural number, then $\mathbb{N}_0$ is the natural numbers, with the notation indicating that you believe that $0$ is a natural number, and you don't want anyone to be confused).  In other words
$$ \mathbb{N}_0 = \{ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, \dotsb \}. $$